# Loop through the matching table when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamically generated html code which looks like :

```
<div class="systeme">
    <table method="post" class="table table_cultures">
        <tr class="formRows">
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>Something</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-default valider_systeme_culture">Valider</button>
</div>

<div class="systeme">
    <table method="post" class="table table_cultures">
        <tr class="formRows">
            <td>Something 2</td>
            <td>Something 2</td>
            <td>Something 2</td>
            <td>Something 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-default valider_systeme_culture">Valider</button>
</div>
```

When I click one of the buttons, I want to loop with javascript through the matching table and only this table.

Currently, when I click one button, I get all data of the both tables.

In Javascript, I have this :

```
var table = $(".table_cultures tbody");
table.find('.formRows').each(function (i) { ... });
```

I also tried with the function `.parents()` but after that I can't do a `.find('.table_cultures tbody)`, it doesn't work. The thing is that I need to find `table_cultures tbody` because it allows me to loop through the rows when there is a tbody.

How should I do to loop through the right table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(this).prev('table')` where `$(this)` is clicked button and then you get `prev("table")` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/850/)

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).prev('table').find('.formRows').css('background', 'red')
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but it can work only if there is nothing between the button and the table. In my case, I have elements between. I know that in my example there is nothing but it's a simplified version of my code :/ I edited the fiddle by adding a div just for you to see : https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/852/

Comment: For that second example to find table your code should look like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/854/

Comment: It works in the fiddle but it doesn't when I try to reproduce in real

Comment: For no reason, google chrome just stopped executing some javascript like the click button event. Weird, but it seems to work with your solution, I can loop through the exact table. Thanks ! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Also if you want to then check each `td` you can do it like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/855/

Answer (score 0):

[Nenad Vracar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4620771/nenad-vracar)'s approach is almost okey;but the original question clearly states that the tables are dynamically generated, so delegating the event should be safer.

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function() {
  $(this).siblings('table')
    .find('.formRows')
    .each(function (index, elem) {
      //var $elem = (this);
      //either use the function parameters is the this variable
      //to do something with the current row
    });
});
```

Comment: The function `prev` can't work with me because I have elements between the button and the table. Please see the comment on the other answer

Comment: then just modify the `prev` function to `siblings` if you only have one table there; otherwise use stricter selectors